# action link if authorized

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, authorization

I would like to display an action link only if a user is authorized for the given action. Is there a good way to do that in cshtml without repeating the aurhorization. Not checking the same rights I already set in the attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can store your link in database .
and assign rights according to user .
on view make link according to rights .

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPost]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    [Authorize(Roles = "YourRole")]        
    public ActionResult Create(Product p)
    {
        ...
    }

    @if (User.IsInRole("YourRole"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Create Product", "Create")
    }
```

Comment: That wont work with ASP.NET identity. `IsInRole` throws exception and it is kinda obselete.

Comment: Did you add this attribute to your controller too? [InitializeSimpleMembership]

Comment: that  was last decade there is now ASP.NET identity.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this   helper function in past to only return output when a criteria is met like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString If(this MvcHtmlString value, bool evaluation)
{
     return evaluation ? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

so you can use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create").If(User.IsInRole("Your Role"))
```

it is legible and short

Comment: I have seen this answer and was looking for something that does not involve repeating my rights at two different places.